# Send Data from Server to Client - Angular SSR

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

How do I send data from Server to Client using Transfer State ?

In my app.component.ts

```
 const STATE_KEY = makeStateKey<string>('MY_DATA');

 constructor(private transferState: TransferState) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myData = this.transferState.get<any>(STATE_KEY, null);
    console.log( this.myData)
  }
```

Now server.ts,

```
  server.get('*', (req:any, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, 
      { req, providers: [
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl },
        { provide: 'MY_DATA', useValue: { message: 'Hello from server!' } }
  ] });
  });
```

But above code is not working. Please help